# Javascript reformat or map an array of objects to a new array of new objects? like reformating it and giving new keys (names) for values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

I'm new to Arrays and objects so I was the whole day stuck at making this task I have a this JSON file or array lang (JavaScript) i was searching on StackOverflow also but can't understand them really well:

```js
[
  { "date": "1959:01", "1": 138.89, "2": 139.39, "3": 139.74, "4": 139.69, "5": 140.68, "6": 141.17 },
  { "date": "1959:07", "1": 141.7, "2": 141.9, "3": 141.01, "4": 140.47, "5": 140.38, "6": 139.95 },
  { "date": "1960:01", "1": 139.98, "2": 139.87, "3": 139.75, "4": 139.56, "5": 139.61, "6": 139.58 },
  { "date": "1960:07", "1": 140.18, "2": 141.31, "3": 141.18, "4": 140.92, "5": 140.86, "6": 140.69 },
  { "date": "1961:01", "1": 141.06, "2": 141.6, "3": 141.87, "4": 142.13, "5": 142.66, "6": 142.88 },
  { "date": "1961:07", "1": 142.92, "2": 143.49, "3": 143.78, "4": 144.14, "5": 144.76, "6": 145.2 },
  { "date": "1962:01", "1": 145.24, "2": 145.66, "3": 145.96, "4": 146.4, "5": 146.84, "6": 146.58 },
  { "date": "1962:07", "1": 146.46, "2": 146.57, "3": 146.3, "4": 146.71, "5": 147.29, "6": 147.82 },
  { "date": "1963:01", "1": 148.26, "2": 148.9, "3": 149.17, "4": 149.7, "5": 150.39, "6": 150.43 },
  { "date": "1963:07", "1": 151.34, "2": 151.78, "3": 151.98, "4": 152.55, "5": 153.65, "6": 153.29 },
  { "date": "1964:01", "1": 153.74, "2": 154.31, "3": 154.48, "4": 154.77, "5": 155.33, "6": 155.62 },
  { "date": "1964:07", "1": 156.8, "2": 157.82, "3": 158.75, "4": 159.24, "5": 159.96, "6": 160.3 },
  { "date": "1965:01", "1": 160.71, "2": 160.94, "3": 161.47, "4": 162.03, "5": 161.7, "6": 162.19 },
  { "date": "1965:07", "1": 163.05, "2": 163.68, "3": 164.85, "4": 165.97, "5": 166.71, "6": 167.85 },
  { "date": "1966:01", "1": 169.08, "2": 169.62, "3": 170.51, "4": 171.81, "5": 171.33, "6": 171.57 },
  { "date": "1966:07", "1": 170.31, "2": 170.81, "3": 171.97, "4": 171.16, "5": 171.38, "6": 172.03 }
]
```

Those are like an income for a company for a specified number of years like in the beginning 1959:01 from 1 to 6 are the first 6 months of the year and the same year 1956:07  but diff in ":07" are the values of the last 6 months (1 to 6) of same year so I wanna make the output as follows with the easiest code to understand please.

```js
  "1956": {
    "1": "value",
    "2": "value",
    "3": "value",
    "4": "value",
    "5": "value",
    "6": "value",
    "7": "value",
    "8": "value",
    "9": "value",
    "10": "value",
    "11": "value",
    "12": "value"
  },
  "1957": {
    "1": "value",
    "2": "value",
    "3": "value",
    "4": "value",
    "5": "value",
    "6": "value",
    "7": "value",
    "8": "value",
    "9": "value",
    "10": "value",
    "11": "value",
    "12": "value"
  },
  "1958": {
    "1": "value",
    "2": "value",
    "3": "value",
    "4": "value",
    "5": "value",
    "6": "value",
    "7": "value",
    "8": "value",
    "9": "value",
    "10": "value",
    "11": "value",
    "12": "value"
  }
```

Appreciate help quite a lot.

Comment: There is not enough detail here. In your output are the property names ("1"..."12") coming from the date in the input? Are they the properties with number names in the input? Also how is "value" calculated? Also, can there be duplicate values of "date" (same year and month?) in the input?

Comment: okay just focus with me on the first and second object cause it's same work for the others it's like when you go to 1956:01 you find six months each month has it's own income (value) this object must be concatenated with the other half of the year which is the 1956:07 to form months or numbers from 1 to 12 instead of being two objects having 6 each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
const data=[
  { "date": "1959:01", "1": 138.89, "2": 139.39, "3": 139.74, "4": 139.69, "5": 140.68, "6": 141.17 },
  { "date": "1959:07", "1": 141.7, "2": 141.9, "3": 141.01, "4": 140.47, "5": 140.38, "6": 139.95 },
  { "date": "1960:01", "1": 139.98, "2": 139.87, "3": 139.75, "4": 139.56, "5": 139.61, "6": 139.58 },
  { "date": "1960:07", "1": 140.18, "2": 141.31, "3": 141.18, "4": 140.92, "5": 140.86, "6": 140.69 },
  { "date": "1961:01", "1": 141.06, "2": 141.6, "3": 141.87, "4": 142.13, "5": 142.66, "6": 142.88 },
  { "date": "1961:07", "1": 142.92, "2": 143.49, "3": 143.78, "4": 144.14, "5": 144.76, "6": 145.2 },
  { "date": "1962:01", "1": 145.24, "2": 145.66, "3": 145.96, "4": 146.4, "5": 146.84, "6": 146.58 },
  { "date": "1962:07", "1": 146.46, "2": 146.57, "3": 146.3, "4": 146.71, "5": 147.29, "6": 147.82 },
  { "date": "1963:01", "1": 148.26, "2": 148.9, "3": 149.17, "4": 149.7, "5": 150.39, "6": 150.43 },
  { "date": "1963:07", "1": 151.34, "2": 151.78, "3": 151.98, "4": 152.55, "5": 153.65, "6": 153.29 },
  { "date": "1964:01", "1": 153.74, "2": 154.31, "3": 154.48, "4": 154.77, "5": 155.33, "6": 155.62 },
  { "date": "1964:07", "1": 156.8, "2": 157.82, "3": 158.75, "4": 159.24, "5": 159.96, "6": 160.3 },
  { "date": "1965:01", "1": 160.71, "2": 160.94, "3": 161.47, "4": 162.03, "5": 161.7, "6": 162.19 },
  { "date": "1965:07", "1": 163.05, "2": 163.68, "3": 164.85, "4": 165.97, "5": 166.71, "6": 167.85 },
  { "date": "1966:01", "1": 169.08, "2": 169.62, "3": 170.51, "4": 171.81, "5": 171.33, "6": 171.57 },
  { "date": "1966:07", "1": 170.31, "2": 170.81, "3": 171.97, "4": 171.16, "5": 171.38, "6": 172.03 }
]

const formated={};

for(let obj of data){
  const formatDate=obj['date'].split(":")[0];
  formated[formatDate]={...obj};
  delete formated[formatDate]['date']
}

console.log(formated)
```

Here the variable `formated` is an object that looks like this:

```
'1959': {
    '1': 141.7,
    '2': 141.9,
    '3': 141.01,
    '4': 140.47,
    '5': 140.38,
    '6': 139.95
  },
  '1960': {
    '1': 140.18,
    '2': 141.31,
    '3': 141.18,
    '4': 140.92,
    '5': 140.86,
    '6': 140.69
  },
  '1961': {
    '1': 142.92,
    '2': 143.49,
    '3': 143.78,
    '4': 144.14,
    '5': 144.76,
    '6': 145.2
  },
  '1962': {
    '1': 146.46,
    '2': 146.57,
    '3': 146.3,
    '4': 146.71,
    '5': 147.29,
    '6': 147.82
  },
  '1963': {
    '1': 151.34,
    '2': 151.78,
    '3': 151.98,
    '4': 152.55,
    '5': 153.65,
    '6': 153.29
  },
  '1964': {
    '1': 156.8,
    '2': 157.82,
    '3': 158.75,
    '4': 159.24,
    '5': 159.96,
    '6': 160.3
  },
  '1965': {
    '1': 163.05,
    '2': 163.68,
    '3': 164.85,
    '4': 165.97,
    '5': 166.71,
    '6': 167.85
  },
  '1966': {
    '1': 170.31,
    '2': 170.81,
    '3': 171.97,
    '4': 171.16,
    '5': 171.38,
    '6': 172.03
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah man absolutely gorgeous snippet of code i just need last step is to concatenate the first object with the second object so it's 12

Comment: I just need one more step is to concatenate every single object with the next object to form a full 12 months year like 1956:01 with the 1956:07 to make a whole year